# Error during training on ResNet50: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 7, 7], but got input of size [8, 196608] instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

python v `3.7.3`, pytorch v `0.4.1`, using jupyter

I am working on creating an image classifier using transfer learning with ResNet50 as the base model.  I've run across an error that I don't understand how to debug, even after searching for solutions online.  I'm not sure why my dimensions are so off.  Any help on what to do would be appreciated.
Also, any book recs on Deep Learning using Pytorch would be great :)

***Code for final layer of ResNet:***

```
fc_inputs = model.fc.in_features

model.fc = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            ('fc1', nn.Linear(fc_inputs, 256)), 
            ('relu', nn.ReLU()),
            ('dropout', nn.Dropout(0.2)),
            ('fc2', nn.Linear(256, 25)),
            ('output', nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
]))

model.classifier = classifier

print(model)
print(model.classifier[0])
print(model.classifier[3])

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr = 0.001) 
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)
```

***code for training:***

```
epochs = 1
steps = 0
running_loss = 0
print_every = 10


for epoch in range(epochs):

    for images, labels in dataloaders['train']:

        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)  #this flattens it?
        steps += 1

        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        logps = model(images)

        loss = criterion(logps, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

        if step % print_every == 0:
            model.eval()
            test_loss = 0
            accuracy = 0

            for images, labels in dataloader:
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

                logps = model(images)
                loss = criterion(logps, labels)
                test_loss += loss.item()

                ps = torch.exp(logps)

                top_ps, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
                equality = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
                accuracy += torch.mean(equality.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()

            train_losses.append(running_loss / len(dataloader['train']))
            test_losses.append(test_loss / len(dataloader['test']))

            print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}.."
                  f"Train loss: {running_loss / print_every:.3f}.."
                  f"Test loss: {test_loss/len(dataloader['test']):.3f}.."
                  f"Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(dataloader['test']):.3f}")


            running_loss = 0
            model.train()
```

***error:***

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-8f88694d7909> in <module>
     16         optimizer.zero_grad()
     17 
---> 18         logps = model(images)
     19 
     20         loss = criterion(logps, labels)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    137 
    138     def forward(self, x):
--> 139         x = self.conv1(x)
    140         x = self.bn1(x)
    141         x = self.relu(x)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in forward(self, input)
    299     def forward(self, input):
    300         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 301                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    302 
    303 

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 7, 7], but got input of size [8, 196608] instead
```

***EDIT: I removed `images = images.view.shape[0], -1`, which was converting my tensor to `[8, 196608]`.  But now I am receiving a new error:***

`RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [8 x 8192], m2: [2048 x 256] at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1532509700152\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMath.cpp:2070`

Comment: What is your image size? Note that the input into resnet should be of the the size `(batches, channels, width, height)` (aka channels should be before image size. Some of the image-reading function put channel after the image size

Comment: @9mat When I print the results for the size of each image, they all come back as `torch.Size([8, 3, 256, 256])`.  Could you please be more specific about what I should change for the input into ResNet?

Comment: You are using images of a different size than what `resnet` usually takes (3*224*224), which is fine, but you need to adjust the number of output features from `resnet`. Normally reset would take in `224*224` image and produce `2048` features. Your input is `256*256`, thus the output would be `32*32*2048`. You cannot use the default `model.fc.in_features == 2048`, and need to change that to your actual number of features. You also need to flatten out the last layer before feeding it to tour own classifier.

Comment: Or an easier approach is to resize your images to `224*224`

Comment: @9mat Yep, that fixed that error!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What is `classifier`? Why do you add another layer (`classifier`) to the model after the `output`?

My guess is you do not need `classifier`, since you have already had the softmax output from the `fc` layer. Try:

```
fc_inputs = model.fc.in_features

model.fc = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            ('fc1', nn.Linear(fc_inputs, 256)), 
            ('relu', nn.ReLU()),
            ('dropout', nn.Dropout(0.2)),
            ('fc2', nn.Linear(256, 25)),
            ('output', nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
]))

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.fc.parameters(), lr = 0.001) 
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)
```

Comment: I changed it to your code because that makes sense overall, but I am still getting the same error, so the issue must be elsewhere.